# Visual Studio : Different Size in Memory for same executable in XP and Windows7

Tags: c, memory, console, size, executable

I have a windows console application developed using Visual Studio Professional 2010 in C.
For test purposes i am running it on two systems.In one system(Windows XP) the task manager reports size in memory as approximately 2000 K  and in other system it is only 600 K.
No change is there in the executable file size.(300K only).

The XP system generated the exe using Visual Studio 2010 express
and the Windows 7 System using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
In both cases the executable size is exactly the same.

Why is this so?How can i make the size same?

Is it some issue with the dlls loaded by the system.
The dlls used by the program differ for some cases.

I checked the dlls loaded by the two systems using :

tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq [programname]"

### Output in Windows XP system :

```
                               ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,
                               MSVCR100D.dll, WS2_32.dll, msvcrt.dll,
                               RPCRT4.dll, NSI.dll, mswsock.dll,
                               user32.dll, GDI32.dll, LPK.dll, USP10.dll,
                               IMM32.DLL, MSCTF.dll, wshtcpip.dll
```

### Output in Windows 7 system :

```
                              ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, MSVCR100D.dll,
                              WS2_32.dll, ADVAPI32.dll, RPCRT4.dll,
                              Secur32.dll, msvcrt.dll, WS2HELP.dll,
                              mswsock.dll, hnetcfg.dll, GDI32.dll,
                              USER32.dll, IMM32.DLL, wshtcpip.dll
```

Thanx Xen

Comment: What surprises you in the fact that the two OSes are sufficiently different internally that you're able to observe the difference in some ways?

Comment: Are you creating the same output type in both systems? (ie either both "debug" or both "release")

Comment: i have not expected this much difference between the memory sizes.

Comment: I guess that is a normal thing.I checked notepad.exe in taskmanager.On XP it is taking 4000K and in Win 7 ,only 900K.In XP file size is 68K,but in Win7, size is 175K

Answer (score 0):

[VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) shows summary information and a detailed process memory map. You can save layout of memory consumption in a file and then doing the comparison for different os versions.

Distribution of the file in memory depends of the operating system version. Windows 7 reduce footprint memory consumption and load time by the exe via [MinWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin) (you can see new dll kernelbase.dll).

Comment: Thankyou sergmat,for that info

Comment: VMMAP is a great tool.I Thank you for suggesting that.